# VSTO ClickOnce self signed certificate and Trusted Publisher

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, vsto, clickonce

I have two certificates which looks the same to me but apparently not to ClickOnce deployment process. Both certificates are self-signed and both are in Trusted Root Zone on the machine where the application will be installed (thus they both don't have issuer, they are roots).

One of those certificates is generated using Visual Studio publish tab using "Create Test Certificate" button and the other one is generated by me using openssl cli

Here's how they look in cert preview

1. created with VS

[image]

2. created with opensll

[image]

Now, the one generated with Visual Studio appears as Trusted Publisher when I install the app whereas my certificate is shown as Untrusted (however when I check the certificate manually - it appears as trusted in Windows).

Here are cli commands I'm using to create certificate using openssl. Note that I'm using the default openssl config (version 1.0.2h)

```
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 4096
openssl req -new -x509 -days 999 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -in ca.crt -inkey ca.key -out ca.p12
```

I can't figure out why my certificate appears as untrusted, that is, what VS cert generator does more than I do in openssl. How can I see and compare the properties of both certificates to see what differs them that matters for ClickOnce installer.

I also tried to explicitly specify that the certificate is for Code Signing (in the Extended Key Usage) -- the result was still the same

Comment: have you found the reason why it wasn't working?

Comment: Unfortunatelly no. Perhaps if you t-up, theres some slight chance that SO will bump this thread